# Placing a div outside a viewport without changing the orginal width. Using Skrollr plugin.

Tags: html, css, skrollr

I'm currently fiddling with a parallax site using Skrollr. I want to create a curtain effect when I scroll down, I change the left and right of two divs 'sliding' open.

Now the problem I encounter is that when I scroll the divs left or right there placed outside of my 100% width outside of my viewport. So then I can scroll vertically, something I don't want. 
Is there a way to force to keep the width as wide as possible?

A codepen to show the problem:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eKJxs

Any ideas?

Comment: You could animate the `width` to prevent the elements from exiting the viewport at all. But `overflow-x:hidden` should also do the job as suggested below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding overflow-x: hidden; to the body seemed to work for me.